# Putting a wpf button in a windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a large, dated looking windows form project. I want to rework it in my spare time, one form at a time, with beautiful wpf. Is this even possible?

I'm thinking I would have to create a separate project, compile it as a library, add a reference to it in the first project, and call the new window vs the old window?

Or would I have to make windows with hosted elements?

Perhaps the most practical approach is to simple redo the whole thing in one go?

Comment: @DourHighArch Not a duplicate of that question; this is asking about merging WPF code into an existing windows forms project.

Comment: the Window-by-Window approach sounds good to me. Make sure you use proper DataBinding as you refactor from winforms to WPF though. Almost zero code-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you *could* do this. As you say, you could host the WPF elements in Windows forms, allowing you to change one page at a time.

You could also do it the other way, creating a WPF project and hosting the windows forms elements. The good part of that is that you have a normal WPF app when you are done (at the cost of some "startup time" to host the forms stuff).

If you can't release it piecemeal, I would just re write the whole thing, as "One page at a time" doesn't give you any benefit. If you can, your approach seems reasonable.

Comment: I like this approach, doing it reverse and ending up with a normal wpf app when I am done. And I appreciate what HighCore said about DataBinding. This approach will also allow for the opportunity to clean up existing code as I go. Also I can focus on changes in the existing code and put forms into the wpf project when I'm 100% sure they aren't going to undergo changes in the near future.

Comment: Yeah, definitely write the WPF the "right" way. No need for Windows Forms style code in a WPF app.